# On hover div, show button near that div?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

So i have a little user gallery and i want when the user enters his gallery to see a delete button when he hovers the image. I tried so many things but nothing worked out.

```
while($rowUser = mysql_fetch_array($queryuserGallery)){
        $display_fullsize_image[] = '
        <li  class="span3" style="width:130px;" >
            <div  class="thumbnail" style="border: none; box-shadow:none; height:200px; "> 
                <a  href="userimages/fullsize/'.$rowUser['fullsize_name'].' " rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is the description">
                <img  src="userimages/thumb/'.$rowUser['thumb_name'].'"  class="img-polaroid"  class="hoverme" alt="This is the title" /></a>
                        <p><a href="#" id="deletebuttonusergallery" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger">Detele</a>  </p> 
            </div>
        </li>
                        ';
    }
```

And the jquery

```
$("div.thumbnail").hover(
         function(){
            var selected = $(".btn").attr("id");
            $(selected).css("display", "block"); 
        },
        function(){

            $(selected).css("display", "none");  
        }
 );
```

So I take the `id` of the button because I will make it with unique number and I want the delete button to appear only on the hovered `div`. Any solutions? And tnx for helping !

Problem solved ! Guys you are lightning fast  , Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div.thumbnail").hover(
        function() {
            var selected = "#"+$(this).find(".btn").attr("id");
            $(selected).css("display", "block"); 
        },
        function(){
            var selected = "#"+$(this).find(".btn").attr("id");
            $(selected).css("display", "none");  
        }
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is ALMOST fine with your code. The problem is that you grab the ID of the element to display but you do not add the hashtag to the selector, here is an updated version that should work:

```
$("div.thumbnail").hover(
         function(){
            $(this).find(".btn").show(); 
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find(".btn").hide();  
        }
 );
```

Or in CSS:

```
.thumbnail > .btn{
display:none;
}
/*Hover will not work in IE6, it only accepts hovers on links.*/
.thumbnail:hover > .btn{
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use the ID. You can just use the jQuery selector:-

```
$("div.thumbnail").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).find(".btn").show(); 
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find(".btn").hide();  
        }
 );
```

Also, rather than setting the CSS display property you can use jQuery's hide and show methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```
$("div.thumbnail").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".btn").toggle();
});
```

- `toggle` will simply show/hide the btn element, as you hover in and out.
- `$(this)` will make sure you are able to find the button in the current scope.

Comment: The problem with toggle is if you enter the element twice without exiting the first time... The reaction then becomes shifted. (Try to alt tab while on the element and come back in the page or have the mouse over the element before the DOM gets fully loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use mouseenter and mouseleave like this:

```
$("#mainImage").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#deleteBtn").show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $("#deleteBtn").hide();
});
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dpxvk/1/